# Dynmically placing the input types inside(table) a <td> tag - innerHTML tag is not working in internet-explorer 

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I need to dynamically place input types inside a `<td>` tag - innerHTML() method is not working in Internet Explorer.  It works fine in Mozilla.

This is the way I'm placing the input types in the JavaScript, where ValueCol is the `<td>` id, On some action I have to change the control to text box.

```
   document.getElementById("ValueCol").innerHTML = "<select name=\"type\" id=\"periodPass\" onchange=\"javascript:AmountOnPeriodPass(this);\"> <option selected=\"selected\" >Select a Pass</option><option>10-day Pass</option><option>Monthly Pass</option>";
```

It works fine in Mozilla but not in Internet Explore. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried jQuery? You could do something like `$.('#cellId').append('yourhtmlstring');`

Answer (score 2):

Well, as described in [QuirksMode Compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html), innerHTML doesn't work fine in IE for the tables. You have to use the regular DOM manipulation.

Comment: Good call. I suggest putting a DIV inside the TD and working with the DIV instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot to close the `<select>` element. Perhaps that's of influence?